# How do I get the properties or the info of a file using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

I need to write the properties or at least the info of a file I have only the name of (here: "text2.txt") to a textfile.
I tried various ways but each time I just get the properties of the Desktop folder but not the file.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
try
    tell application "Finder"
        set this_folder to path of (folder of the front Finder window) as alias
    end tell
on error
    -- no open folder windows
    set this_folder to path to desktop folder as alias
    set is_desktop to true
end try

tell application "System Events"
    set file_list to the name of every file of this_folder
end tell

tell application "Finder"
    set theFile to path to desktop folder
    set myList to {}
    repeat with n from 1 to count of file_list
        set currentFile to item n of file_list
        set the_filePath to this_folder
        set the_filename to currentFile
        if currentFile contains "text2.txt" then
            set {creation date:creaDate, modification date:modDate, name:fName, displayed name:dName, name extension:nExt, description:descript, URL:fPath} to properties of the_filePath
            set theText to creaDate & "#" & modDate & "#" & fName & "#" & dName & "#" & nExt & "#" & descript & "#" & fPath
            do shell script "echo " & theText & ">> $HOME/Desktop/FileProperties.txt"
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mostly have it right already.

Finder windows have a 'target', which is the folder that the window looks at. You can get and set the target normally. Everything below the try statement is unchanged.

```
try
    tell application "Finder" to set this_folder to target of front window as alias
    
on error
    set this_folder to (path to desktop) as alias
    set is_desktop to true
end try
```

As alternatives, the script could use TextEdit or its own 'write' command to create the text document. If you're curious, let me know and I'll add those options.

---

Okay… here is a script you can try that should handle the writing within applescript. I've made a few other tweaks, all of which are commented (which unfortunately, make the script appear longer than it really is).

Applescript has a built-in 'File Read/Write suite' which you can read about each command in the Language Guide [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW59), but in a nutshell, you use these commands to write to a new file, replace or append text to an existing file.

p.s. I changed some of your variable names

```
-- Make front window specifier a global var. Unnecessary if you integrate System Events block into Finder block (see below)
global fw

tell application "Finder"
    try
        set targFol to target of front window as alias
        set fw to front window
    on error
        set targFol to (path to desktop) as alias
        set fw to make Finder window to targFol
    end try
    
end tell
```

The system events block below could also be handled by the Finder. If the folders you're rooting through don't typically have thousands of files in them (or if the alternative line is sufficient), you should consider doing so, as the primary advantage of using System Events is performance with high file counts. I don't think any changes would be required beyond removing the appropriate 'tell/end' statements.

```
tell application "System Events"
    -- Some filtering options as an alternative to the repeat loop
    set txFiles1 to files of targFol whose kind is "Plain Text Document"
    set txFiles2 to files of targFol whose kind is "Plain Text Document" and name is "text2.txt"
    set txFile to item 1 of txFiles2
    
    -- Alternatively, you can just use the file itself, without any of the rigmarole.
    set txFile to file "text2.txt" of targFol
end tell

tell application "Finder"
    set {creation date:creaDate, modification date:modDate, name:fName, displayed name:dName, name extension:nExt, description:descript, URL:fPath} to properties of targFol
    
    set newText to creaDate & "#" & modDate & "#" & fName & "#" & dName & "#" & nExt & "#" & descript & "#" & fPath as text
end tell

-- Write the properties as text to a text file -- requires the 'class furl' bit to work
set tf to (path to desktop as text) & "FileProperties.txt" as «class furl»
-- Alternatively, you could create the text file in the target folder 
-- set tf to (targFol as text) & "FileProperties.txt" as «class furl»

close access (open for access tf)
write newText to tf as text

-- And some obvious things you can do with your new text file
tell application "TextEdit" to open tf
tell application "Finder" to select tf
set rtext to read tf
```

Comment: First, sorry for the late reply! YES, I'd like to know how to write directly w/o using the CLI. That would ease the handling.

Comment: @pixi Whew! That just got a lot bigger.

Answer (score 0):

I made a few adjustments to your code.  Maybe something like this will help you out.

```
property theFile : "text2.txt"

tell application "Finder"
    try
        -- Gets The Name Of The Front Finder Window If There Is One Opened
        set containerName to name of front Finder window as POSIX file as text
        -- Checks If The File "text2.txt" Exists In That Folder
        -- fileExists Will Be Set To True Or False Depending On The Results
        set fileExists to (containerName & theFile) as alias exists
    on error errMsg number errNum
        -- If Either Of The Previous Commands Throws An Error
        -- This Will Give You An Option To Choose A Folder Where You Think
        -- The File "text2.txt" Is Located
        activate
        set containerName to my (choose folder with prompt "Choose A Folder") as text
    end try
    try
        -- Checks If The File "text2.txt" Exists In The New Chosen Folder
        set fileExists to (containerName & theFile) as alias exists
    on error errMsg number errNum
        -- If "text2.txt" Does Not Exist In This Folder Either, Script Stops Here
        return
    end try
    delay 0.1
    -- If fileExists Is Set To True From Previous Commands 
    if fileExists then
        set fullFilePath to (containerName & theFile) as alias
        set {creation date:creaDate, modification date:modDate, name:fName, displayed name:dName, name extension:nExt, description:descript, URL:fPath} to properties of fullFilePath
        set theText to creaDate & "#" & modDate & "#" & fName & "#" & ¬
            dName & "#" & nExt & "#" & descript & "#" & fPath
        tell current application to (do shell script "echo " & theText & ¬
            ">> $HOME/Desktop/FileProperties.txt")
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: I always have to select a folder here, even if the folder the file resides in is opened. The line "set fileExists to (containerName & theFile) as alias exists" throws the error the "on error errMsg number errNum" reacts on. I also can't get this result by "display dialog fileExists". Do youn mind to clarify what's wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: @pixi I added some comments to the code which should explain what each step of the process does

Comment: That clarifies it a bit. But the dialog is still popping up. When I remove the "try" the "set fileExists to (containerName & theFile) as alias exists" says "The file ":Desktoptext2.txt" could not be found." number -43 from ":Desktoptext2.txt". Seems a problem to build the path. Any idea?